# Python: recurse through list of strings - how to tell the difference?

Tags: python, string, list, types, enumerable

I have the following code

```
def printmylist( mylist ):
    """
    print tree
    """
    try:
    for f in mylist:
        printmylist( f )
    except:
        print( "        " + mylist )
```

hoping to get output like:

```
root
   branch
     leaf
     leaf
```

but since a string is enumerable, I get

```
r
o
o
t
.
.
```

Checking for type seems to be unpythonic, so how would a Pythonian go about this?

Comment: A pythonista would first complain that "flat is better than nested", then admit that "practicality beats purity" and would proceed to do a manual typecheck.

Answer (score 5):

The cleanest way that I know of is to use [`types.StringTypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html#types.StringTypes) (not to be confused with [`types.StringType`](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html#types.StringType)):

```
isinstance(var, types.StringTypes)
```

Alternatively:

```
isinstance(var, basestring)
```

Documentation for the [`types`](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html) module indicates that the latter is the preferred way in recent versions of Python 2.x.

Comment: python 3.x users simply use: `isinstance(var, str)` (every strings are unicode in python 3, the unicode type disappeared)

Comment: In 2.x, it's easier to use `basestring`, which is the ancestor of both `str` and `unicode` types.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following pythonic approach to this problem.  No `isinstance()` calls required.  Therefore it even works with various custom C++ string classes I have wrapped in python.  I don't think those isinstance() based methods would work in those cases.  Plus the OP explicitly asked for a solution that does *not* involve type checking.  Pythonistas check behavior, not type.

The trick here involves the observation that strings have an unusual property: the first element of a one-character string is the same one-character string.

```
"f"[0] == "f"
```

This works in python 2.x:

```
def is_string(s):
    try:
        if (s[0] == s[0][0]):
            return True
    except:
        pass
    return False
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest one is `if type(f) == str`

Sometimes it's better to use if's than exceptions.

EDIT:
Due to larsmans comment, I don't recommend this option. It is useful in simple usage, but in professional coding it is better to use `isinstance`.

Comment: ... and also the most unreliable. `isinstance(f, str)` would be better.

Comment: I haven't run into a situation, where type() is unreliable, but maybe I'm just lucky. If you say so, than surely `isinstance` is a better solution. I leave the answer though, just for anyone to see the difference.